Paper request: Alberto Collino, Griffiths’ infinitesimal invariant and higher K-theory on hyperelliptic Jacobians
I am trying to locate a copy of the paper by Alberto Collino titled "Griffiths’ infinitesimal invariant and higher K-theory on hyperelliptic Jacobians".
I can neither download nor purchase it online. It was originally published in Journal of Algebraic Geometry, vol. 6, 1997.
It appears to be widely cited, but unfortunately the author has passed away, and I can't request a copy from him.

it's only been digitized from 2002 onwards, so you can't access it online, but many libraries have the journal https://search.worldcat.org/title/46761984
